# How to access an input field and write text to it inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, rpa

I need some guidance from you. I am trying to automate a process with WinAutomation software and i need to open a web page and just insert login name, password and press log in. All seemed very easy but i got stuck because i first time encountered iframe. The login is in an iframe and i cant access it. What I can do is execute javascript function. I wanted to ask is it posbile to access it using javascript and populate those fields with text? Tried googling it but every answer i find people are asking how to access it on their own page so they have more control over it than I do. I just have the webpage name and that's it. And I have minimal knowledge on javascript.
The page is: https://mit.nykredit.dk/erhverv/?kort=2

I tried just some simple code with getElementById but the ID of the input field seems to change everytime you refresh the page. I would be really grateful for any help.

Comment: You can access contents of iframe only if's from same domain, otherwise you cannot.
Code to access frame from same domain
var frame = document.getElementById("fram").contentWindow;
frame.document.getElementById('put id here');

Comment: So if it's not on the same domain i have no way to input those fields?

Comment: Nope, I think so because of security reasons.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you.